# Doctrine 2 Concurrency issues

Tags: php, symfony, concurrency, doctrine-orm

I'm writing unit tests for a Symfony 2 / Doctrine 2 application and I'm encountering what looks like a concurrency issue.

The code looks like this:

```
$obj = new Obj();
$obj->setName('test');

... etc ...

$em->persist($obj);
$em->flush();

...

$qb = $em->getRepository('Obj');
// Select object using DQL

$this->assertTrue($obj !== null);
```

At this point $obj is often null. I.e. the DQL query has failed to find it. If I add breakpoint and pause execution somewhere before executing the DQL, $obj is always found. If not it's usually not found but occasionally it is found.

I have tried wrapping the insertion in a transaction:

```
$em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

$obj = new Obj();
$obj->setName('test');

... etc ...

$em->persist($obj);
$em->flush();

$em->getConnection()->commit();
```

This doesn't seem to help.

I have tried adding a pause between the insert and the DQL query:

```
sleep(1);
```

This results in the expected behaviour consistently. Thus my conclusion that this is a concurrency issue. Or at least something to do with Doctrine not immediately writing through on flush.

Is there any way with Doctrine 2 to force a write to the database to complete? Or an event to listen for? Or am I doing something else wrong here?

Comment: Enable query log for your database server and see how queries are emitted. For what you observe to be a concurrency problem you must have 2 connections that run concurrently. The first is possible but unlikely, the second is impossible in php (by default).

Comment: It looks like concurrency isn't the problem after all. I found a time dependent error that was causing my inconsistent results. If you want to add your comment about logging as an answer I'll mark that as the answer since I found my bug straight away having followed your advice.

Comment: You better post the answer with explanation of the problem

Comment: I've posted an answer, but I was wanting to give you the reputation points... thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Having followed zerkms' advice to enable logging I quickly tracked the problem down to a fault in my own code. There was no concurrency issue.

On my Mac I did the following:

Edit: `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`
Add these lines:

```
general_log_file = /tmp/query.log
general_log      = 1
```

Then:

```
brew services restart apache2
```

Next I tailed the file:

```
tail -f /tmp/query.log
```

I saw the two queries - an insert and a select - executing in the right order. Running those queries directly in MySQL client revealed the error in my code.

Note: putting the log into `/tmp/` ensures the logs are deleted everytime I log out.